# how to replace the number with the "image width" in vote page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vote

```
<form action="/votes/vote" method="post">
  <% for option in @vote.options %>
    <%= option.name %>
    <%= option.quantity %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="op[]" value="<%= option.id %>" /><br />
  <% end %>

  <input type="hidden" value="<%= @vote.id %>" name="id"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`<%= option.quantity%>` is the number of the vote; I want to replace it with an image more visual. How?

option1.quantity=15;  =>: =====15px(columnar image)======

option1.quantity=30;  =>: =============30px(columnar image)===============

Comment: you mean an image that dynamically has the value of option.quantity ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to replace a number with an image, but what image?

Comment: @alokswain image's width is the option.quantity

Comment: well, then you could use image_tag and in the width option that it provides you could pass option.quantity.
<%= image_tag(path_to_image, :width => option.quantity) %>
Sorry to send code here, just not sure if this is what you want, so dint post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question, but if you want something "more visual", what about creating DIV like a color bar:

```
%div{:style => "background-color: green; height: 20px; width: #{option.quantity}px;"}
  = option.quantity
```

you can replace color with some background columnar image of course:

```
%div{:style => "background-image: url('some_columnar_image_path'); height: 20px; width: #{option.quantity}px;"}
```

Comment: hi ,@bender how to use "%div{...}"?? both <%= %div{...} %> and <%div{...} %>can't work  -_-!